# transpose dataframe changing columns names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Could you please help me in transforming the dataframe `df`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['a1',2,3],['b1',5,6],['c1',8,9]],columns=['A','B','C'])
df
Out[37]: 
    A  B  C
0  a1  2  3
1  b1  5  6
2  c1  8  9
```

in `df2`

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=[[2,5,8],[3,6,9]],columns=['a1','b1','c1'])
df2
Out[36]: 
   a1  b1  c1
0   2   5   8
1   3   6   9
```

The first column should become the column names
and then I should transpose the elements...is there a pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little trick with slicing, initialise a new `DataFrame`.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.T[1:], columns=df.A.tolist())
```

Or,

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[:, 1:].T, columns=df.A.tolist())
```

```
  a1 b1 c1
0  2  5  8
1  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

For general solution use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with transpose:

```
df1 = df.set_index('A').T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None)
```

Or remove column `A`, transpose and build new `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.drop('A', 1).T.values, columns=df['A'].values)
print (df1)

   a1  b1  c1
0   2   5   8
1   3   6   9
```